# Select multiple items from a tableview - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I need to add a `TableView` and i should be able to click several Items in that `tableview` and save it to a `NSMutable dictionary` or something suitable.

I know that you have to use a `NSMutable Dictionary` for this. But i don't understand how to do this.

Can someone please point a good tutorial or provide some sample codes for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a delegate method for that.
First make sure your table view is set up well ([delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [datasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) and then
implement delegate 's :
`(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

You access the selected row index with : `[indexPath row]`.
And then you can store this value.

Answer (score 0):

THere was a post by Matt Gallagher at [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html) about this that you might find illuminating.

A bit dated, but the principles will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSMutableDictionary` in this method as:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", cell.Label.text] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:"Key%d", indexPath.row]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your data model.
First of all you need a NSMutableArray not a NSMutableDictionary;

```
//declare an NSMutableArray in the interface
@interface Class : SuperClass {
NSMutableArray *_arrayWithMySelectedItems;
}

//in one of your init/preparation methods alloc and initialize your mutable array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_arrayWithMySelectedItems = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

//now before you forget it add release in your dealloc method

- (void)dealloc {
[_arrayWithMySelectedItems release];

[super dealloc];
}

//add this following code to your didSelect Method part of tableView's delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//if you have only one category, you will probably have something like this
[_arrayWithMySelectItems addObject:[dataModelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a string inside didselect row of tableview then  give that string = [your populated array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]; then add that into dictionary or nsmutable array according to your wish.